# What databases support logarithmic prefix search?

Tags: sql, algorithm, search, full-text-search, logarithm

What databases have a logarithmic method to fetch all the prefixes of a string?

For example:

```
key
---
air
all
antilope
antivirus
apple
```

when I query for prefixes of `an` it will return

```
key
---
antilope
antivirus
```

I know that it is possible because you can perform a binary search asking: Give me the smallest index greater then `an` and smaller then `ao`

A trivial way of doing it in most databases would be with a like query:

```
select * from my_table where key like 'an%'
```

How ever my understanding is that it is performing a linear search and hence it is not efficient for me.

Comment: Look into [ordered key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Key-Value_Store) or prefix tries

Answer (score 1):

With a pattern such as `'an%'` almost all databases will use an index on `my_table(key)`.  They can do this because the pattern starts with constant values.

This is looking for an *exact* match on the prefix, using a tree based search.

Some databases have more extensive index structures -- particularly Postgres -- and these also support text-based searching.

Comment: I know that this in not true for Sqlite where such queries require a full table scan. Even their `FTS-5` that have a dedicate [prefix index](https://sqlite.org/fts5.html#prefix_indexes) will use extra space to memorize the actual prefix rather then performa a binary search. So can you please provide an official link that will support what you are saying

Comment: @IlyaGazman Gordon is right.  The "range scan" for SQLite in your link looks for an exact match on the prefix in the index, using a tree based search.  SQLite's dedicated prefix lookup index for really fast reads falls squarely under the "more extensive index structures" category.  That feature saves you the logic of walking the leaves of a tree, which in some use cases can be significant.

Comment: @btilly I don't think you quite understood me. The prefix index in the provided link is indeed how you describe it, but it's not what I want. In order for sqlite to achieve this performance improvement they pay with storage price. I believe that it's achievable without paying with storage, just as I described in my question